# Does an SQL timeout stop execution on the server?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Consider this. You have a .NET application that calls a stored procedure on SQL Server. Execution takes a while. By default, the client will time out after 30 seconds, causing an `SqlException` to be thrown.

When this happens, does this stop any remaining statements in the stored procedure from being executed? Or do they continue regardless of the client timeout?

Comment: I think the client only initiate the stored procedure, then the sql server take care of that.